# Make each row of a data frame a different line graph and plot on the same plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a code like the following:

```
x1 <- list(1,2,3,4,5)
x2 <- list(1,4,7,8)
x3 <- list(5,6)
x4 <- list(9,0,0,5,6,7)
myList <- list(x1, x2, x3, x4)

df <- data.frame(t(sapply(myList, function(x){
c(x, rep(tail(x, 1), max(lengths(myList)) - length(x)))})))
```

Which creates a data frame like this:

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1  1  2  3  4  5  5
2  1  4  7  8  8  8
3  5  6  6  6  6  6
4  9  0  0  5  6  7
```

How can I create a separate line graph for each row of the data frame and plot them all on the same plot where X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6 show the changes in the y-value over time.

Comment: Try `matplot(t(df), type = 'l', xaxt = 'n');legend('topright', colnames(df), col = seq_along(df), fill = seq_along(df));axis(1, at = seq_along(df), labels = colnames(df))`

Comment: Can I ask why everything is stored in `list`? And, on that, why you construct `df` as you do?

Comment: Did my answer below answer your question? If not please feel free to let me know how we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply copying [akrun's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48268928/make-each-row-of-a-data-frame-a-different-line-graph-and-plot-on-the-same-plot-i#comment83521273_48268928) in an attempt to get the question closed.

```
matplot(t(df), type = 'l', xaxt = 'n')
 legend('topright', colnames(df), col = seq_along(df), fill = seq_along(df))
 axis(1, at = seq_along(df), labels = colnames(df))
```

[image]